# Can you translate this SELECT statement

Tags: sql

I'm trying to understand code written by someone else. The table `closure` has 3 columns named `ancestor`, `descendant`, and `length`.

The query I'd like help with is:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (ancestor, descendant, length)
 SELECT a.ancestor, 12, a.length+1
   FROM closure a
   WHERE a.descendant=11;
```

Normally I'd expect column names after a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Is that really the complete statement? Looks like part of a hierarchy traversal; I'd expect to see a query like that as part of a larger, recursive query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's selecting `ancestor`, the literal number `12`, and then the value of `length` plus one. It does this for the rows where the column `descendant` equals 11.

There's nothing stopping you from selecting literals and doing arithmetic in a select statement.

If you're wanting to access the values by a column name in your application code, you probably want to name those last two by using `AS somename` (e.g. `SELECT 12 as number, ...`)

Comment: Let's make sure I understand correctly. First, the query identifies all the records where the `descendant` is `11`. This results in a list of records. Then it takes those records and it replaces the value of `descendant` by the number `12`, and it (effectively) adds one to the value of `length`. Correct? (Then it inserts those into `table1`, but my question was really about the `SELECT`.)

Comment: Basically. It doesn't retrieve `descendant` from the table in the `SELECT`, or "replaces" it. It just uses the literal value `12` provided in the `SELECT` clause. It does however, retrieve the value for `length` for that row, and adds 1 to it. And then yes, it does insert back into the table.